# Python - Observer pattern - Object has no attribute

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-3.x, finalizer

I try to run one example from the book "Python Essential Reference" involving observer pattern, but there is a problem with attribute. When the AccountObserver executes `__del__` the error raises - Object has no attribute 'observers'. I don't know what wrong is with the code, so any help would be very appreciate.

```
class Account(object):
    def __init__(self, name, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.observers = set()
    def __del__(self):
        for ob in self.observers:
            ob.close()
        del self.observers
    def register(self, observer):
        self.observers.add(observer)
    def unregister(self, observer):
        self.observers.remove(observer)  
    def notify(self):
        for ob in self.observers:
            ob.update()     
    def withdraw(self, amt):
        self.balance -= amt
        self.notify()


class AccountObserver(object):
    def __init__(self, theaccount):
        self.theaccount = theaccount
        self.theaccount.register(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.theaccount.unregister(self)
        del self.theaccount

    def update(self):
        print("Balance is %0.2f" % self.theaccount.balance)

    def close(self):
        print("Account no longer in use")


a = Account("Ketty", 200000)
a_mama = AccountObserver(a)
a_tata = AccountObserver(a)
a.unregister(a_mama)
a.withdraw(10)
```

And the output:

```
Balance is 199990.00
Account no longer in use
Exception ignored in: <bound method AccountObserver.__del__ of <__main__.AccountObserver object at 0x024BF9F0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Projects\TestP\src\main.py", line 28, in __del__
  File "F:\Projects\TestP\src\main.py", line 13, in unregister
AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'observers'
Exception ignored in: <bound method AccountObserver.__del__ of <__main__.AccountObserver object at 0x024BFEB0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Projects\TestP\src\main.py", line 28, in __del__
  File "F:\Projects\TestP\src\main.py", line 13, in unregister
AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'observers'
```

Comment: are you using `python 3`?

Comment: py 2.7.. I cannot reproduce it

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can using python3.4, `AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'observers'`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I ran this in a 3.4 shell. Will try with a separate file now.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: ah, reproduced, due to the clearing order.

Comment: I believe this is because of del of accountorder class

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python cleans out the module when the interpreter exits. At that point all instances and classes are deleted, and that means that `Account.__del__` can run **before** `AccountObserver.__del__`. The order in which the classes are cleared depends on the global namespace dictionary order, which is random thanks to the [random hash seed](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) used. `Account.__del__` deletes `self.observers` so any later call to `account.unregister()` will raise an `AttributeError`.

Your code relies on the classes and attributes all still being there when the module exits. That means you can get both `KeyError` errors (as `a_mama` was already unregistered), or `AttributeError` as the `self.observers` attribute is already cleared (because `Account.__del__` cleared it).

There is a big fat warning in the [`object.__del__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> **Warning**: Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()` methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and a warning is printed to `sys.stderr` instead. Also, when `__del__()` is invoked in response to a module being deleted (e.g., when execution of the program is done), other globals referenced by the `__del__()` method may already have been deleted or in the process of being torn down (e.g. the import machinery shutting down). For this reason, `__del__()` methods should do the absolute minimum needed to maintain external invariants. Starting with version 1.5, Python guarantees that globals whose name begins with a single underscore are deleted from their module before other globals are deleted; if no other references to such globals exist, this may help in assuring that imported modules are still available at the time when the `__del__()` method is called.

The work-around is to make your `__del__` method more robust in the face of such exceptions:

```
def unregister(self, observer):
    try:
        self.observers.remove(observer)  
    except (KeyError, AttributeError):
        # no such observer, or the observers set has already been cleared
```

Comment: what is the difference between python 2 and python 3?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Python 3 uses a random hash seed by default, so dictionary order is even less predictable. It can happen in Python 2 as well, but dictionary order is more stable so you don't see it happen here unless you run Python with the `-R` switch.

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt response and explenation.